# Where is Stark Tower located?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, the-avengers-2012

In the Avengers movie, Tony Stark builds a tower in New York City. It is big, it is shiny, it is tall. It's all the things that Tony Stark loves, especially in his buildings.

During the battle in the third act:

> ...we see the ground team (Hawkeye, Black Widow, Captain America) are pretty much camped out near Grand Central station. It would seem that Stark Tower isn't too far from there, given that Captain America's primary mission is to keep the Chitauri within a 3 block radius of Grand Central. That leads me to believe the portal (which is above Stark Tower) is located close by, because otherwise the mission objective would be laughable and tactically unwise.

Based on the establishing shots, I was wondering: Where is Stark Tower located? And, furthermore:

> Is Stark Tower located in lieu of the MetLife building?

Comment: Augh, I kept forgetting to post this question.

Comment: @Keen Muahahaha.

Comment: Ahem: Grand Central *Terminal* (not station, since it is an End of the Line). :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, it's the MetLife building.  [According](http://io9.com/5906886/designing-the-avengers-the-art-of-marvels-most-ambitious-movie) to the production designer:

> Tony Stark bought the iconic MetLife Building (formerly the PanAm Building) and ripped off the top adding his own piece of parasitic architecture to the top.

Comment: I wonder if this is established in actual movie or, preferably, comic canon (via dialogue, text, or other verifiable in-universe evidence), instead of just as a moviemaker's design choice?

Comment: Well, the location is pretty obvious; in our universe, the MetLife building totally ruins the view of the Grand Central building looking south on Park Avenue. There's not very many buildings around Grand Central with that same angle.

Comment: You can see it in several scenes, especially during the climactic battle.  There's the base of a building, with a ton of construction scaffolding, then above that is the start of Stark Tower.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://lawandthemultiverse.com/2012/05/09/the-avengers-arc-reactors-and-nyc-zoning-laws/) blog post claims that it is on the site of the MetLife building. They don't seem to specify a source, but if you both came to that conclusion independently that has to count for something, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are both right...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetLife_Building

Popular culture
In The Avengers, the building is deconstructed to make way for Stark Tower.

Answer (score 0):

In a shot of lower Manhattan in *Doctor Strange*, the Avengers' Tower can be seen very clearly. In relation to the Empire State Building and Rockefeller Center, the tower seems to be near or on the corner of Park Ave and 44th St. with the iconic "A" logo facing North and Grand Central Station behind it; I do not know if they are supposed to be connected buildings or not.

I actually did find an address: Tony and Pepper have a listed address of 200 Park Ave, which is pretty much exactly where I guessed it to be...