# Where is the Oscorp Tower located?

Tags: spider-man, marvel, the-amazing-spider-man

Along the same vain as [Where is Stark Tower located?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/16517/3383) from the **Avengers** movie.

---

In *The Amazing Spiderman* the Oscorp tower seems to be towards the center of NYC around 54th Street (as they told people to evacuate *south* of 54th Street).

Is it possible that the Oscorp Tower is right by where the Sony Building is now (55th Street and Madison Avenue)? Or is it in some location close to there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They used the base of the [Hearst Tower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearst_Tower_%28New_York_City%29) for the Oscorp tower.  The Heart building is at 57th and 8th Avenue.

I don't recall them being specific with the location of the Oscorp Tower, other than it appeared to be up on 7th Avenue (where the cranes were moved to give Spiderman a clear path using his web) and north of Times Square.  I don't believe the visual they had during the crane sequence would have fit a building on Madison (and it may barely fit a building on 8th Avenue, if that building were very tall).

Comment: Where is the source for them using the Hearst Tower?

Comment: Me, living in New York City, near Columbus Circle, walking by the Heart Tower on a regular basis.  Note that it's only the base used in the movie.  The real-life glass portion was changed to something bigger and glassier.  There are also some other notes: http://www.onlocationvacations.com/2011/05/01/fan-photos-from-the-set-of-spider-man-in-nyc/ and http://www.mnn.com/lifestyle/arts-culture/blogs/hearst-tower-makes-spider-man-appearance

Answer (score 7):

The Oscorp building's address is most likely 1180 Avenue of the Americas (6th Avenue between 46th and 47th St).  It might also be one block north at 1212 Avenue of the Americas (6th Avenue between 47th and 48th St.).

The best shot is at the time stamp 00:39:05.  I took a screen shot and marked a few buildings that I know (and used Apple Maps 3D on my iPad to get the address).  The Oscorp building appears to be one block north and on the same side of 6th Avenue as #5 (on the east side of the avenue).  It is also 2-3 blocks south of #1 and 1-2 blocks south of #2 (both also on the east side of 6th avenue).  The MetLife building is also in the foreground at the far right.  It appears to be a couple of streets south of the Oscorp building (which makes since because 44th St. would go right through the MetLife building).

[image: establishing shot of Oscorp tower]

1) 1258 Avenue of the Americas (6th Avenue between 49th and 50th)

2) 1230 Avenue of the Americas (6th Avenue between 48th and 49th)

3) 500 5th Avenue (between 42nd and 49th)

4) 1114 Avenue of the Americas (6th Avenue between 42nd and 43rd)

5) 1160 Avenue of the Americas (6th Avenue between 45th and 46th)

At time stamp 1:47:58 the news says that there is a city-wide evacuation of everything south of 54th street.  This makes since because the gas/fighting took place south of Oscorp and then moved north (see next paragraph).

The shootout between the Lizard and the police (where he changes them) (beginning near 01:40:47) is suppose to take place on 6th Avenue (Avenue of the Americas) near a subway that has the BDFM line and the 7 line.  For a split second you can see a street sign that says 6th Avenue/Avenue of the Americas.  The station the film shot at is different the station it is suppose to be.  The only stations that have access to both the BDFM and 7 lines are the Bryant Park stations at 6th Ave. & 41st St. and on 42nd St. between 5th and 6th Ave.  Neither of these stations were used in the filming because Bryant Park is nowhere to be seen.

At 01:48:29 the construction worker asks his co-worker: "You still friends with Matthews, that crane operator down on 6th Avenue?"  A few seconds later, at 01:49:03, an order goes out over the radio for all tower cranes on 6th to swing out over the avenue.

But there are some inconsistencies:

At 00:14:42 Peter is looking up at the building for the first time and behind him you can clearly see an awning that says, "3 Columbus Circle." 3 Columbus Circle takes up an entire block and is bordered by 8th Avenue, Broadway, 57th, and 58th.

At 01:42:01 Peter comes out of the sewer on his way to the final fight of the movie.  He clearly comes out near a Bed Bath & Beyond, but the only 3 near midtown don't make sense for the movie. The most ideal location is near the Lincoln center at Columbus Ave. (aka 9th Ave), Broadway, and 65th St.  This is the most ideal because a few minutes later (at 01:49:16), after he is shot and about to ride the cranes, there is a shot of the Oscorp building lit up with searchlights and the cranes are being moved out over 6th Avenue.  These are definitely cranes north of the Oscorp building because the Empire State Building (5th Ave between 33rd and 34th St) is seen in the background and to the left of Oscorp (where it would be if Oscorp was on 6th Avenue between 46th - 48th St).

Comment: Nice leg work on this answer!

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion, thank you for your hard work.

Answer (score 1):

I was aware of at least 3 locations that the Oscorp Tower appeared in different shots. The only one I was sure of, though this was certainly not where the 'cranes' sequence led us to believe it was, was in place of the Metlife Building. This is seen in a aerial shot directly over the building. I found it pretty annoying that they didn't place it in one location and stick with that.